# PhPBB3 editing footer 

Tags: forum, phpbb3

I have read a few guides and they say to edit overall_footer.tpl? Which I'm guessing is the same as overall_footer.html and when I edit that I don't see any changes on my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

If you make any changes to the templates it might be necessary to empty out your cache and refresh things.  What are you trying to change in your footer?